# How can I simulate/generate mild workload on my Windows laptop?

Tags: laptop, battery, benchmarking, workload-simulation

I've been asked to have a look at a laptop (intended for donation), and I want to estimate the state the battery is in. For that purpose, I would like to simulate a typical, "mild" workload - web browsing, office document creation - and let that run, until the battery dies. Naturally, if *I* were using that laptop as my own, I wouldn't need to simulate anything and would just time the battery life - but the point is that this isn't a computer I'm personally working on.

If I wanted to simulate an intensive workload, I'd look for stress-test utilities, like primes95 or some benchmarking programs. The challenge here is the *mildness* of the workload.

Answer (score 1):

There are tons of free stress test programs out there.  Im sure at least some of them have the ability to set the level of stress.

Windows 10 and 11 can run Microfoft's [Power Automate](https://powerautomate.microsoft.com/).  You can use that to simulate a light workload.

If you can install the [Windows Subsystem for Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install) (WSL), you can install the Linux program [stress](https://linux.die.net/man/1/stress).  Stress can test many aspects of a computer and the load amount is configurable.